# auto populate field in access form doesn't work when I reopen my program

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

There are two tables in my database:
- Table `courses`  Fields: `CourseID`, `course name`
- Table `student` Fields: `StudentID`, `Student name`, `CourseID`, `course name`

I want to create a form for this student table in which whenever I enter `courseID` value the course name should be automatically displayed in the `coursename` field.

To do this I created a relationship between these two tables and also created a trigger called `After Update` on `courseID` attribute of student form. What this does is, it fills the attribute value in the form based on the `courseID` which I have entered from courses table.

This works fine when I create a new program but the problem comes when I reopen my access program.

It just doesn't work at all. Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Welcome!  "doesn't work" isn't very descriptive of your problem. Please [edit] your question to add sample data, an example of desired result, the code you're using and specifically where it seems to be having a problem.  Also, check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) and see "[ask]" as well as **how to create a [mcve]**.  Also, here's a "perfect question" [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the sites' top user. You can also see the [help/on-topic] for information about what's on topic on this site. Good luck!

Comment: Also, I'd recommend this (free/basic) tutorial as a good place to start: [**QuackIt: Microsoft Access Tutorial**](//quackit.com/microsoft_access/tutorial/) and [Microsoft's **Database Design Basics**](//support.office.com/article/database-design-basics-eb2159cf-1e30-401a-8084-bd4f9c9ca1f5). Also here's a this video on [**DB Planning**](https://youtu.be/i72fVNqfWL4).

Comment: Course info should not be saved in Students table. Students table should just have info about students, not courses. This is a many-to-many data relationship. Need a 3rd "junction" table StudentsCourses that associates students and courses. Then use form/subform arrangement for data entry. Basic relational database principle. I also recommend you complete tutorial.